# The breakpoint linked location is incorrect when debugging vue in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I have coded with es6 in my vue project(vue-cli3.0).
When i writed a debugger in my page,it stopped indeed but in a wrong place
So has anybody been encountered with this problem?

As follows,my debugger in the red rect targets the blue line showed below.

### my code written

[image: my code written]

### debugging in chrome

[image: debugging in chrome]

Comment: Have I described it clearly?

Comment: Not everyone can read the images, either because images are blocked at their work, or they cannot read white on black text. I suggest you use a code block and then explain in text that the debugger stops on totally differend line in a differend file

Comment: in fact，my condition is even worse than you think,cause the code stops in another file,but i can see the environment parammeters when i type it in the console

Comment: which leads a hard debug for me,sad

Comment: the upper debuger targets the position showed below

Comment: I'm only trying to explain why your question was downvoted, while your core issue is valid, the question text itself doesn't explain very much

Comment: oh,I see, let me think about how to correct it properly.Thank you